# comparing time in if statement does not work python

Tags: python

```
    launch_time = Parsed_list[7] #STRING FOR to similar time --- how it looks 19:29:59
    print(launch_time,flush=True)


    while True:
        #GETS CURRENT TIME
        now = datetime.now() #current time
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("Await Mode:",current_time,flush=True)
        
        #when 19:29:59 == 19:29:59 break loop
        #compares current time with launch time if its equal it will launch
        if( str(current_time) == launch_time):
            break; # breaks the loop bot runs

        time.sleep(1)
```

so im creating code that suppose to be able to launch when current time is equal to launch time but for some reason when I compare current time to launch time it doesn't activate the if statement. Im not sure why its not working the outputs can be exactly the same but for some reason it won't run.

Comment: Why don't you print `current_time` and `launch_time` before the if condition and see what values they have?

Comment: @lllrnr101 I did  they are the exact same

Comment: Worked for me if I set `launch_time = '08:06:04'` Maybe your `launch_time` is not string? print `type(launch_time)` also just to verify.

Comment: @lllrnr101 yes it works if you set it just like that but if your getting it from an array position which is a string it doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `str(current_time)`, `launch_time` and their type(launch_time)? Paste a few lines of your output/